# Change AD-Password from client by console / VBScript

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, password, vbscript

I have an AD-environment, but a few machines are used as workgroup-machines (and I can't change this).

My target is to have a script which changes the AD-Password on the server from a client machine. Most answers in the web are for clients attached in the domain, so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> won't work here.

Some said it is possible when setting up Outlook Web Access (OWA), but I think this is a bit big just for the benefit of changing passwords.

I tried out a few VB scripts but nothing is working. How would you solve my problem?

Comment: If these are Windows XP Professional based workstations, I believe it can be done in the user accounts window.  I am using Windows 7 Professional and I don't see this option available for network passwords.  If they are XP, you may want to look for more information regarding that process.

Comment: So your "client" machine is domain-joined and you're logged in using a domain account? And your "server" is not domain-joined (workgroup), but you have a local admin account on it that allows you access? If so, does this local admin account share the same username as your domain account?

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend you if you have used a vb scripts and then also its not working please go for a third party tool, such as Lepide active directory self service or you can also go for manaengine password reset tool. Both do the same function but Lepide is a freeware tool with the limitation on the numbers of users.

Answer (score 1):

Are there a lot of accounts involved?

Is there a spare domain machine available for users to log into? They can then just RDC into that dedicated machine, change their domain password and log out.

You can also take a look at [PsPassword](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx) by Sysinternals: **pspasswd \\server -u UserWithDomainPasswordresetPermissions -p psswd Username NewPassword**

Comment: ill try, thx for the hint

Comment: No problem, let me know how it works out.